# TSQL, reconstruction of a dimensional table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table  ***Players*** (id, PlayerName).

| id | PlayerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Messi |
| 2 | Ronaldo |

and a lot of other tables (at least 6), with attributes and temporal limit
example 1

**Salary** (idPlayer, StartDate,EndDate, SalaryEuro)

| idPlayer | StartDate | EndDate | SalaryEuro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 28/02/2020 | 10000 |
| 1 | 28/02/2020 | 31/03/2020 | 10050 |
| 1 | 01/04/2020 | 01/01/2099 | 11000 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 04/07/2020 | 20000 |
| 2 | 05/07/2020 | 01/09/2020 | 20500 |
| 2 | 02/09/2020 | 01/01/2099 | 20700 |

example 2 **TEAM**

| idPlayer | StartDate | EndDate | TEAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 24/02/2020 | Inter |
| 1 | 25/02/2020 | 31/03/2020 | Roma |
| 1 | 01/04/2020 | 01/01/2099 | Juve |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 04/07/2020 | Barcellona |
| 2 | 05/07/2020 | 01/10/2020 | Juve |
| 2 | 02/10/2020 | 01/01/2099 | Barcellona |

and so on. All attributes tables have the same structures, no records with null values, and at least 1 record for main Player table.

Expected result is to reconstruct all the historical step of each players for each attribute.

***PlayersHistory***

| idPlayer | PlayerName | StartDate | EndDate | TEAM | SalaryEuro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Messi | 01/01/2020 | 24/02/2020 | Inter | 10000 |
| 1 | Messi | 25/02/2020 | 28/02/2020 | Roma | 10000 |
| 1 | Messi | 01/03/2020 | 31/03/2020 | Roma | 10050 |
| 1 | Messi | 01/04/2020 | 01/01/2099 | Juve | 11000 |
| 2 | Ronaldo | 01/01/2020 | 04/07/2020 | Barcellona | 20000 |
| 2 | Ronaldo | 05/07/2020 | 01/09/2020 | Juve | 20500 |
| 2 | Ronaldo | 02/09/2020 | 01/10/2020 | Juve | 20700 |
| 2 | Ronaldo | 02/10/2020 | 01/01/2099 | Barcellona | 20700 |

really don't know how to achieve this.. tried with union, full join ..

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this again, it doesn't work. Because `LAG` will only get the previous row. We need any previous data that is not null. If anyone can fix this, feel free to edit.

<s>A `UNION ALL` followed by a window function should do the trick.

Basically, you union all the tables together, with nulls in the missing columns, then a `LAG` to get the previous value for the missing columns.</s>

But because the dates might be equal, we need to group the values by date (`MIN` is fine here as ther will only be one value.

```sql
SELECT t.Id, p.PlayerName,
    t.StartDate, t.EndDate,
    Team = ISNULL(Team,
        LAG(Team) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Id ORDER BY StartDate)),
    SalaryEuro = ISNULL(SalaryEuro,
        LAG(SalaryEuro) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Id ORDER BY StartDate))
    --etc
FROM (
    SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate,
        Team = MIN(Team), SalaryEuro = MIN(SalaryEuro) --etc
    FROM (
        SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate, Team, SalaryEuro = NULL
        FROM Team
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate, NULL, SalaryEuro
        FROM Salary
        -- etc. add columns and union all for other tables
    ) t
    GROUP BY Id, StartDate, EndDate
) t
JOIN Players p ON p.Id = t.Id
ORDER BY t.Id, t.StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The key question is - can you trust your data (in terms of consistency) - or whether your logic is to spot any issues.

As a side note. Always include statements like this (especially for simple problems), to allow to reproduce data, to help others help you :)

```
create table [players] (id int,player_name nvarchar(100))
create table [salary] (idPlayer int, StartDate date ,EndDate date, SalaryEuro int)
create table [team] (idPlayer int, StartDate date ,EndDate date, TeamName nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[players]
           ([id]
           ,[player_name])
     VALUES
           (1,'Messi'),(2,'Ronaldo')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[salary]
           ([idPlayer]
           ,[StartDate]
           ,[EndDate]
           ,[SalaryEuro])
     VALUES


 (1,'2020-01-01','2020-02-28',10000)
,(1,'2020-02-28','2020-03-31',10050)
,(1,'2020-04-01','2099-01-01',11000)
,(2,'2020-01-01','2020-07-04',20000)
,(2,'2020-07-05','2020-09-01',20500)
,(2,'2020-09-02','2099-01-01',20700)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[team]
           ([idPlayer]
           ,[StartDate]
           ,[EndDate]
           ,[TeamName])
     VALUES

(1,     '2020-01-01','2020-02-24',  'Inter'     )
,(1,    '2020-02-25','2020-03-31',  'Roma'      )
,(1,    '2020-04-01','2099-01-01',  'Juve'      )
,(2,    '2020-01-01','2020-07-04',  'Barcellona')
,(2,    '2020-07-05','2020-10-01',  'Juve'      )
,(2,    '2020-10-02','2099-01-01',  'Barcellona')
```

Now, here is your solution:

```
SELECT [p].[id]
      ,[p].[player_name]
      ,[t].[TeamName]
      ,[t].[StartDate] as [player_in_team_start]
      ,[t].[EndDate]  as [player_in_team_end]
      ,[s].[StartDate] as [player_salary_in_team_start]
      ,[s].[EndDate] as [player_salary_in_team_end]
      ,[s].[SalaryEuro]
      ,CASE WHEN [s].[StartDate] BETWEEN [t].[StartDate] and [t].[EndDate] THEN 'OK' ELSE 'CHECK DATA' END as [test1] --salary must start within time when player is in the team
      ,CASE WHEN [s].[EndDate] BETWEEN [t].[StartDate] and [t].[EndDate] THEN 'OK' ELSE 'CHECK DATA' END as [test2] --salary must end within time when player is in the team
  FROM [dbo].[players] [p]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[team] [t]
        ON [p].[id] = [t].[idPlayer]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[salary] [s]
        ON [p].[id] = [s].[idPlayer]
    WHERE 1=1
        AND [s].[StartDate] BETWEEN [t].[StartDate] and [t].[EndDate] -- player's salary in a team is only possible while player is in the team

  ORDER BY [p].[id]       
      ,[s].[StartDate] 
      ,[s].[EndDate] 
      ,[t].[StartDate] 
      ,[t].[EndDate]
```

Now, why did I use LEFT JOIN? I assume that Players is my master record, and I want to display a row for each player, then I left join to each table.

While my join is only on ID (try it, commenting out WHERE) - this will produce 18 records, which is incorrect initially.

That's a good start on small dataset (if you don't have 1000s of records in each table).

Then you need to organise your columns so that their sequence make sense, so it is easy for you to follow and validate your examples.

Optionally you can test your logic by using CASE statements first, so you flag wrong records, rather than completely excluding them. Once you are happy with them, you convert them to WHERE... and exclude the bad stuff.

As you can see in the result I produced, the CASE statements helped highlight inconsistency in sample data:

| id | player_name | TeamName | player_in_team_start | player_in_team_end | player_salary_in_team_start | player_salary_in_team_end | SalaryEuro | test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Messi | Inter | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-24 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-28 | 10000 | OK | CHECK DATA |
| 1 | Messi | Roma | 2020-02-25 | 2020-03-31 | 2020-02-28 | 2020-03-31 | 10050 | OK | OK |
| 1 | Messi | Juve | 2020-04-01 | 2099-01-01 | 2020-04-01 | 2099-01-01 | 11000 | OK | OK |
| 2 | Ronaldo | Barcellona | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-04 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-04 | 20000 | OK | OK |
| 2 | Ronaldo | Juve | 2020-07-05 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-07-05 | 2020-09-01 | 20500 | OK | OK |
| 2 | Ronaldo | Juve | 2020-07-05 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-09-02 | 2099-01-01 | 20700 | OK | CHECK DATA |

Comment: there is no inconsistency in datas though. There is no relation between salary and teams..

Comment: and definitevely won't work. even without where condition...

Comment: logically there is a relationship (even if indirect). salary must come from somewhere?  who is paying salary on 26-02-2020?

Answer (score 0):

At the end.. the trick was to build a table with all the starting date in sequence for each players, using the *union* and not the *union all*

```
    SELECT idPlayer, 
           StartDate, 
           ISNULL(nextDate, '01/01/2099') AS NewEndDate, 
           Typeofchange,
           CASE
               WHEN TypeofChange = 'Team'
               THEN LAG(SalaryEuro, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY idPlayer
           ORDER BY StartDate)
               ELSE SalaryEuro
           END AS NewSalary,
           CASE
               WHEN TypeOfChange = 'Salary'
               THEN LAG(TeamName, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY idPlayer
                  ORDER BY StartDate)
               ELSE TeamName
           END AS NewTeam
    FROM
    (
        SELECT idPlayer, 
               StartDate, 
               DATEADD(dd, -1, LEAD(StartDate, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY idplayer
               ORDER BY StartDate)) AS NextDate, 
               TeamStartDate, 
               TeamEndDate, 
               SalaryStartDate, 
               SalaryEndDate, 
               TeamName, 
               SalaryEuro, 
               Typeofchange
        FROM
        (
            SELECT cd.idPlayer, 
                   cd.StartDate, 
                   t.StartDate AS TeamStartDate, 
                   T.EndDate AS TeamEndDate, 
                   TeamName, 
                   s.StartDate AS SalaryStartDate, 
                   S.EndDate AS SalaryEndDate, 
                   SalaryEuro,
                   CASE
                       WHEN S.startDate = T.startdate
                       THEN 'Both'
                       WHEN S.idplayer IS NULL
                       THEN 'Team'
                       WHEN T.idPlayer IS NULL
                       THEN 'Salary'
                   END AS Typeofchange
            FROM
            (
                SELECT idPlayer, 
                       StartDate
                FROM teams
                UNION
                SELECT idPlayer, 
                       StartDate
                FROM salary
            ) AS CD -- change date
            LEFT JOIN teams t ON t.idPlayer = cd.idPlayer
                                 AND t.StartDate = cd.StartDate
            LEFT JOIN Salary s ON s.idPlayer = cd.idPlayer
                                  AND s.StartDate = cd.StartDate
        ) allrec
    ) recWithLead;
```